# accessing and setting label text userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've two userdefault values `username` and `password`, I want to set label which is inside `tableView cell` text those userdefaults, but my code only sets `username` not password

any solution?

```swift
class UDM {
    static let shared = UDM()
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "saved.data")
}
    @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
        UDM.shared.defaults?.setValue(usernameRegister.text, forKey: "username")
        UDM.shared.defaults?.setValue(passwordRegister.text, forKey: "password")
        }  //  userdefaults are set succesfully
```

```swift
// table view controller
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        cell?.setup(with: UDM.shared,with: UDM.shared)
        return cell!
    }
///table view cell
    func setup(with username:UDM,with password:UDM){
        label.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "password") as? String
        label.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "username") as? String
    }
```

Comment: There can be many causes to fix that. 
Is passwordRegister.text contains some Value?? It's good to test the table view label with some dummy Value.

  It also seems that possibly you are using the same label for username and password. It's good to check that too.

label.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "password") as? String
  label.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "username") as? String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are assigning the same label different values.

If your read your code it first assign your label with password then it assign the same label with username. You have to make a label1 or label2.

```
func setup(with username:UDM,with password:UDM){
        label1.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "password") as? String
        label2.text = UDM.shared.defaults?.value(forKey: "username") as? String
    }
```